# trouble installing old 2005 BOOST library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

Gooday everyone

I'm fairly new to ubuntu C programing although I'm
rather experienced in C programing in windows.

I have recently come accross a number of codes written
in 2005 which I'm interested in learning how they work.

Those codes needs BOOST library to compile, however they won't
compile on the newest BOOST version present on my ubuntu 12.04.
I set the gcc compiler on lenient so that it ignores all those error
messages. The code did compile and ran afterwards.

However, when I used GDB debugger to watch how the program flows 
I noticed that there are likely errors in the way the program runs
due to using a different BOOST version rather than it's original. Hence
I like to install the BOOST version corresponding to the code I downloaded.

To do that, I installed Ubuntu 5.04 and BOOST 1.33.0 which seemed to have been created in late 2005. I downloaded it
but I didnt found any detailed instruction on how to install it.
Only vague description on using BOOST jam, I played around with BOOST
jam for quite awhile without success.
And this old BOOST does not have installation commands like
"sudo apt-install boost-dev" style option

Thus I like to ask if anyone can give a easy to understand step by step instruction
on how to install the BOOST library downloaded from the above link.
like.....

- step1: download boost jam from boost webpage
- step2: unpack it in home/boost/ then type make configure

...and so on...

Big thanks for any useful info.

**New Contents appended here**
in response to the comments given

Hi, I went through the info given by your link and
managed to run the boost library examples given by your link.
That is, I can compile a single cpp file with the command

```
g++ -I boost_1_33_0 test.cpp -o test
```

(I'm keeping the boost library and the cpp file to be compiled in the 
 same folder)

However, the program package I'm interested in is build with make (not cmake).
I have some experience writting cmake files but not make files.
And I do not see any link to boost library command in the make file of the
program package. The readme file only has one sentence that says I 
need to have boost installed without explaining what that meant.

I assume it means that either I have to build and do makeinstall the boost or
I could add some lines in the makefile for a link. I thought
maybe you can quickly point out whats missing in the makefile.

The readme file:

> To compile, go into the moses directory and do 'make'. You'll need the
>   latest boost libraries. If compilation still fails for weird reasons,
>   you could try g++ with the -fpermissive (newer versions reject lots of
>   code that was ok with older ones). If you are going to be making
>   changes and recompiling frequently you'll probably want to disable -O3
>   in the makefile (I use templates liberally, so -O3 really speeds up
>   the code, but really slows down compilation).

And the makefile:

```
CC = g++

PROJ_NAME = moses

LINK_FLAGS = -Wall -Iutils/ -Itrees/ -Irewrite -I./ -Imodeling/ -Ifitness/ \
             -Ialignment/ -Isim/ -Ilocal/ -O3
COMP_FLAGS = -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Iutils/ -Itrees/ -Irewrite -I./ \
             -Imodeling/ -Ifitness/ -Ialignment/ -Isim/ -Ilocal/ -O3

src := $(wildcard *.cc) $(wildcard utils/*.cc) $(wildcard trees/*.cc) $(wildcard    modeling/*.cc) $(wildcard fitness/*.cc) $(wildcard alignment/*.cc) $(wildcard main/*.cc) $(wildcard rewrite/*.cc) $(wildcard sim/*.cc) $(wildcard local/*.cc)

obj := $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(src))

all: $(PROJ_NAME)

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAGS) $< -c -o $@

$(PROJ_NAME): $(obj)
    $(CC) $(LINK_FLAGS) $^ -o $(PROJ_NAME)
run:
    $(PROJ_NAME)
clean:
    find -regex ".*~\|.*\.o"|xargs rm -f
    rm -f $(PROJ_NAME)
    rm -f $(PROJ_NAME).exe*

depend:
    makedepend -Y -- $(COMP_FLAGS) -- $(src)



utils/exceptions.o: utils/exceptions.h utils/utils.h
utils/io_util.o: utils/io_util.h utils/tree.h utils/basic_types.h

# ......lots more lines like that.........
```

Comment: Do you need libraries that needs compilation for your project, or only template libraries? because in first case you can ignore boost compilation. otherwise, check http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html, a bit more recent documentation.

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late reply! I got no notification of a comment to my question and did not realized I got a reply. Simply put, the software package I'm interested is compiled with cmake. when I type cmake.. in folder bin, the system informs me boost is missing. I assume this is the first case of your reply? I'll check out the info you send. But please inform me of anything else that maybe of use

Comment: what is missing? headers or libraries? maybe you should put some variable in cmake that specify both headers and library paths.

Comment: Headers are missing, lots of them. I checked the info link you send. I might be able to get it running myself. I'll update this page soon I got some results. Again, Huge Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Hi there, I put my response in the question section, it's too long for the comment section

Comment: Appended to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have an old instruction flying around here for Boost 1.34.1, which reads like this (project-specific stuff cut away):

- unpack boost sources
- `cd` into `tools/jam/src`
- run `./build.sh` to build `bjam`
- `cd` into the main source directory
- `tools/jam/src/bin.linux/bjam threading=multi --layout=system --toolset=gcc --without-python variant=release --prefix=/usr/local install`

The `--without-python` was necessary as the target system didn't have Python installed, which caused the build to fail messily.

Obviously you can / need to fiddle with the individual settings (like threading support, release vs. debug variant) to suit your needs, but it should be a good starting point.

If you need ICU support (for Boost.Regex and Boost.Locale), it gets more complicated...

Note that the build process has changed over the years; you shouldn't use the same procedure for more up-to-date boost versions. It's just what I used back then.

**Edit:**

As for the second part of your question, the Makefile doesn't need to refer to Boost explicitly *if boost is installed in the standard system directories*.

You do not have to state `-I /usr/include` for compilation as that is searched automatically; the same goes for `-L /usr/lib` during linkage.

The fact that the author of the Makefile copied the compiler flags into the linker flags verbatim doesn't really help intuitivity either... ;-)

If you have Boost in a custom directory (either the headers only, or by stating a custom directory in the `--prefix` option of my build instructions), you need to make the following modifications (look for "boost"):

```
LINK_FLAGS = -Wall -Iutils/ -Itrees/ -Irewrite -I./ -Imodeling/ -Ifitness/ \
             -Ialignment/ -Isim/ -Ilocal/ -L /path/to/boost/libs -O3 
COMP_FLAGS = -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Iutils/ -Itrees/ -Irewrite -I./ \
             -Imodeling/ -Ifitness/ -Ialignment/ -Isim/ -Ilocal/ \
             -I /path/to/boost/includes -O3
```

That should do the trick. As the Makefile does not link any of the Boost binaries (e.g. `-l boost_program_options` or somesuch), it seems that it makes use of the Boost *headers* only, which would make the `-L /path/to/boost/libs` part (and, actually, the whole compilation step detailed above) superfluous. You should be able to get away with simply unpacking the sources and giving the header directory as additional include directory using `-I /path/to/boost/headers`.

Comment: Hurray!!! I manged to get it running! Thanks a thousand for the instructions! Hope that also helps someone else. I have one final question, in order to put in the debug flags for GDB, where do I put in the '-g' flag? Is it right behind the first line of the make file, like: "CC=g++ -g"?    By the way: The only difference with BOOST_1_33_1 I used was that build.sh script and bjam was in a differnt folder. and threading=multi gives 'dont know how to do that' from the system during compilation.